# Setting a default for nosuchelementexception for multiple variables in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, error-handling, defaultdict

So I am scrapping multiple rows of a table and many of them are either available or not for different pages. What I want to do is to detect which field is not available and supply it on a variable and set a default variable i.e.,  None to it.
For eg,

```
try:
        field1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
        field2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
        field3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
        field4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
        field5 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")

        dict_ = {"field1":field1, "field2": field2.....}

except NoSuchElementException:
       # some code to detect which element not found and supply a default value None to it
       defaultVaule = None
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject `if else None` statement as follows:

```
field1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
field1=field1.text if field1 else None
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to reverse the order - initialize using default values and populate if retrieval succeeds element-wise.

```
dict_ = {"field1":None, "field2": None.....}

try:
        dict_["field1"] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
try:
        dict_["field2"] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value="somexpath")
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a better way the same day I asked question to handle exception through a separate function. It just I forget to update it.

first import

`from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

then call this function

```
def box_items():
    try:
        ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=//*[@id='some_id']/div/a).text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            ele = "None"
        return ele
```